# nginx : having issue with setting up multi domain on single ip(vps)

Tags: nginx, server, vps, nginx-location

so my vps is running `ubuntu 17.04` and i have configured my dns pointing to my vps on both domain `@`

here is my nginx folder structure

[image]

this is my server block code for w3saver.com

`filepath: /etc/nginx/sites-available/w3saver.com`

```
`server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name w3saver.com www.w3saver.com;

    root /var/www/w3saver.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } }`
```

and this server block is for w3youtube.com

`filepath: /etc/nginx/sites-available/w3youtube.com`

```
`server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
server_name w3youtube.com;

    root /var/www/w3youtube.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } }`
```

so my problem is when ever i go to "w3youtube.com" page i get redirect to "w3saver.com" page *(both domains are serving same page)* so what is wrong with that i can't able to figured it out!

**ps: i am expecting both domain should serve dedicated static html pages. insted of single html on both domains**

this is what i am getting right now.

`result in domain1`

[image]

also same `result in domain2`
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: i am really sorry for my stupid question it was my spelling mistake in directory so thats why i was having error.

Comment: ps: how to delete a post?